# Reindex Magento 2 with morethan 500000 products

Tags: e-commerce, large-data, reindex, magento2.4

I have a website having more than 500000 products, but as the product count is much higher than usual I cannot do the reindexing successfully.

Getting the timeout error on SSH. Reindex mode is set to Update By Schedule.

How do I run the reindex in this case?

Looking for solutions :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indexers are scoped and multi-threaded to support reindexing in parallel mode. It parallelizes by the indexer’s dimension and executes across multiple threads, reducing processing time.

check this
[https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#:~:text=Index%20parallelization%20affects%20scoped%20indexers,be%20paralleled%20by%20store%20views](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#:%7E:text=Index%20parallelization%20affects%20scoped%20indexers,be%20paralleled%20by%20store%20views).

maybe it can help :)

Comment: Are you suggesting to execute individually
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product

Comment: Read Reindexing in parallel mode from above link to acheive reindexing parallel mode..